# Error building Microsoft Mixed Reality WebRTC Source code

Tags: uwp, webrtc, windows-mixed-reality

I've been trying to build Microsoft's [Mixed Reality WebRTC](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC) source code for UWP x64 configuration following the [help document](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/building-windows.html) and ran into some [peculiar issues](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/issues/533#issue-678311696). Running the [build script](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/master/tools/build/build.ps1), throws errors stating some files are missing, but they are actually available in the required location.

Something like

```
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '........\xplatform\webrtc\sdk\windows\wrapper\impl_org_webRtc_Au dioBufferConfiguration.cpp': No such file or directory [D:\MixedReality-WebRTC\external\webrtc-uwp-sdk\webrtc\windows\p rojects\msvc\Org.WebRtc.WrapperGlue.Universal\Org.WebRtc.WrapperGlue.vcxproj]
```

What is baffling is that some of the files in the same folder is being recognized but not others and it is the exact same set of files no matter the machine or branch used. I'd be grateful for any suggestions on what could be missing or the factors to check, that might shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll be better off posting an issue on the Mixed Reality GitHub repo. You'll also need to include a larger snippet of the build log messages. Also just in case you missed it you do need to do a `recursive` clone before building https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/building-windows.html.